# mysql Delete from table after 100

Tags: mysql

Now I am trying to keep 100 messages of one user in the database and I am trying to delete the another messages out of 100

my database is mysql. my sql is

```
DELETE FROM userMessage WHERE id = ? limit 100, 9999;
```

but the version of my database don`t support this sql.

thanks:)

Comment: please refer this discussion http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11258/mysql-delete-all-rows-greater-than-n-entries-ordered-by-datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
DELETE FROM userMessage WHERE id not in
(SELECT id FROM userMessage uM where user_id = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100)
```

Comment: This would work, BUT you would need to do, `where id NOT in` instead, otherwise it will simply just delete the first 100 rows.

Comment: DELETE FROM singleMessage WHERE id not in (select t.id from (SELECT id FROM singleMessage uM where ownerId = ? ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 100) as t); this works well thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

Why not select 100 records into a temp table. Then delete the old table and rename the temp table name afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Having unique `id` you can use this query -

```
DELETE t1
FROM
  table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 100) t2 -- Specify your LIMIT values here
  ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE
  t2.id IS NULL
```

This query will delete all records after 100.